# Generate order report by product name by WC_Admin_Report

Tags: php, mysql, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to generate an order report that ordered product contain specific name.

For example I want sales report of product that has title "toy" , which the products includes "car toy", "tools toy" ,"bike toy"...etc.

I want to use `Woocommerce WC_Admin_Report` class to generate the report, but I can't get it works.

```
include_once($woocommerce->plugin_path().'/includes/admin/reports/class-wc-admin-report.php');
$wc_report = new WC_Admin_Report();

$where_meta[] = array(
            'type' => 'order_item_meta',
            'meta_key' => '_product_name',
            'operator' => 'LIKE',
            'meta_value' => 'shirt'
        );

$sold_products = $wc_report->get_order_report_data(array(
        'data' => array(
            '_product_id' => array(
                'type' => 'order_item_meta',
                'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
                'function' => '',
                'name' => 'product_id'
            ),
            '_qty' => array(
                'type' => 'order_item_meta',
                'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
                'function' => 'SUM',
                'name' => 'quantity'
            ),
            '_line_subtotal' => array(
                'type' => 'order_item_meta',
                'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
                'function' => 'SUM',
                'name' => 'gross'
            ),
            '_line_total' => array(
                'type' => 'order_item_meta',
                'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
                'function' => 'SUM',
                'name' => 'gross_after_discount'
            )
        ),
        'query_type' => 'get_results',

        'where_meta' => $where_meta,

        'limit' => 20,

        'order_status' => array( 'completed', 'processing')
    ));
```

The `where_meta` only looks for `woocommerce_order_itemmeta` table where the product name is in `woocommerce_order_items` table, so how can I make search through the `woocommerce_order_items` as well? Something like this?

```
 $where_meta[] = array(
                'type' => 'order_item',
                'meta_key' => 'order_item_name',
                'operator' => 'LIKE',
                'meta_value' => 'toy'
            );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this for your `$where_meta`.

```
$products = new WP_Query( array( 
    's'             => 'shirt',
    'post_type'     => 'product',
    'fields'        => 'ids'
) );

$product_ids = $products->posts;

$where_meta = array (
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'type'       => 'order_item_meta',
        'meta_key'   => array( '_product_id', '_variation_id' ),
        'meta_value' => $product_ids,
        'operator'   => 'IN',
    ),
);
```

Additionally, you can also do it this way. More convenient.
Using `where` instead of `where_meta`.

```
$where => array(
    array(
        'key'      => 'order_items.order_item_name',
        'value'    => '%shirt%',
        'operator' => 'LIKE',
    ),
),
```

Also you need to call this on `init`. So it then should look like this:

```
add_action('init', 'reports');

function reports() {


    include_once(WC()->plugin_path().'/includes/admin/reports/class-wc-admin-report.php');
    $wc_report = new WC_Admin_Report();

    $sold_products = $wc_report->get_order_report_data( array(
        'data' => array(
            '_product_id' => array(
                'type' => 'order_item_meta',
                'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
                'function' => '',
                'name' => 'product_id'
            ),
            '_qty' => array(
                'type' => 'order_item_meta',
                'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
                'function' => 'SUM',
                'name' => 'quantity'
            ),
            '_line_subtotal' => array(
                'type' => 'order_item_meta',
                'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
                'function' => 'SUM',
                'name' => 'gross'
            ),
            '_line_total' => array(
                'type' => 'order_item_meta',
                'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
                'function' => 'SUM',
                'name' => 'gross_after_discount'
            )
        ),
        'where' => array(
            array(
                'key'      => 'order_items.order_item_name',
                'value'    => '%shirt%',
                'operator' => 'LIKE',
            ),
        ),

        'group_by'     => 'order_item_name',

        'query_type' => 'get_results',

        'limit' => 20,

        'order_status' => array( 'completed', 'processing' ),
    ) );

    print_r($sold_products);    
}
```

don't forget the `'group_by'`.

```
    /* sample output of print_r($sold_products);
    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [product_id] => 70
                [quantity] => 3
                [gross] => 36
                [gross_after_discount] => 36
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [product_id] => 53
                [quantity] => 4
                [gross] => 140
                [gross_after_discount] => 140
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [product_id] => 50
                [quantity] => 1
                [gross] => 10
                [gross_after_discount] => 10
            )

    )

    */
```

Comment: Awesome! This really works. Thanks a lot. By the way, do you know how to do pagination in this class as well?

Comment: glad you can make use of it, however, I don't seem to see an easy way of doing it but to use your own way. In any way possible.